# REST Call to get DefaultNewFormUrl

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, rest, ajax, json

I am trying to make a call to the REST service in Javascript to collect the 'DefaultNewFormUrl' for a specific list.

The property is "not returned with the resource" so I need to make a separate call for it but I cant figure out what the URL is that I require, can anyone help please, I have tried the below with no luck.

```
http://<Site URL>/<Web Name>/_api/web/List/<List Title>/DefaultNewFormUrl
```

Comment: First of all it's `/Lists/`, secondly what do you mean by `<List Name>`? You need to query for the list, e.g., with ID or Title

Comment: I don't need all the lists I just need the property "DefaultNewFormUrl" from a single list. And sorry I wrote that wrong I am using the List.Title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just got the [URL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn531433.aspx#bk_ListCollectionGetByTitle) wrong, try this:

```
_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('<List Title>')/DefaultNewFormUrl
```